# Start an activity 10 times but only one at a time

Tags: android, for-loop, android-activity

In my app the number of players can vary. Therefor I use a for loop to collect the name of the player as many times as the amount of players.

The problem is that it starts all the activities on top of each other. So for example if I am going to collect 3 names. Player3 gets to write name first then player 2 then player 1 which is the opposit of the desired order.

What I think would solve the problem is a function that waits for the activity to finish. **sleep until the Intent is back to this one** or something similar. OR just an easier way to start an activity x times and collect x names and store them in my array.

Googling how to wait for an activity to finish and they recommended `startActivityForResult()` but it is not what I had in mind.

```
   { @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if(requestCode == NAME_COLLECT_RESULTCODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                recentCollectedName = data.getStringExtra("name");
            }
        }
    }
    private void collectNames() {
        for (int i = 1; i<=antalSpelare;i++) {
            Intent collectNameIntent =  new Intent(this, collectName.class);
            collectNameIntent.putExtra("playerNum", i);
            startActivityForResult(collectNameIntent, 
    NAME_COLLECT_RESULTCODE);
            names[i] = recentCollectedName; //names is a string array
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your screen please

Comment: Just explain what you exactly want to do..

Comment: Hello Il and welcome to StackOverflow! Reading your _issue_ it appears that you're trying to go against a safe and good programming practice; this is initially evident by the fact that you're trying to go against what the (Android) framework is offering; I believe that you should reconsider this approach and architecture, instead offer something more like either single fragment with a ViewPager that you can keep scrolling left/right to let each user enter his/her player name or even using a DialogFragment and capture all the names. What I'm saying is that your current direction won't end well.

Comment: I want to collect the names of x players. I have an activity "collectName" that collects a name so I want to start it x times. But one time at a time not all at once on top of eachother

Comment: Maybe a screenshot? Or I cannot understand how you 'collect the name'

Comment: The activity collectName. Consist of an Edittext where they can write their name and a confirm button. CollectName returns the name as result

Comment: According to you, using the above code, player 3 gets his/her name first and then player 2 followed by player 1. Am I right?

Comment: Martin I felt the same that there should be a smoother way. But I don't see how using scrolling instead of them poping up one at a time would solve the problem. I am quite new to Android and lack knowledge of what the framwork is offering like you rightfully say. Because I don t know how many times I will scroll since it depends on the amount of players. And what to return also depends

Comment: That is right adarsh Anurag! even though the for loop goes from 1 to amountOfPlayers

Comment: Then store results in this manner. names[amountofPlayers - i] = recentCollectedName;

Comment: The activity you open, I think gets stacked upon one another. activityx1 followed by activityx2 and activityx3. Use activityx3 to store result for player1, activityx2 for player2 and activityx1 for player3.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense Adarsh the thing is the for loop seems to execute before the result is given and recentlyCollectedName is not going to be initialized then if that is the case like i think it is

Comment: Exactly they get stacked

Comment: I think if the activity collectName would return name+Playernum(int given as extra when I start collectName) for the different names i could change in my onActivityResult for all the max 10 different codes(I allow max 10 players) but this feels a bit unsmooth

Comment: Then pass playerNum as requestCode and onActivityResult check resultCode==RESULT_OK and then names[requestCode] = data.getStringExtra("name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is very, very bad idea. Starting activities in loop, and, above that, trying to schedule that, it's clock ticking on the bomb.

Anyway, you haven't explained your problem properly. Are users allowed to see each other usernames?

If they are, why don't you just create RecyclerView/ListView that will list EditText field for each user? Fill whole list, and then in the end just save everything at once.

If they are not, than have only one activity with one text field. And then, when first user clicks Save button, you just clear text field and let second user to enter username, and so on. You just need to implement logic for keeping tose usernames somewhere. Local database, or List parameter in activity that would just append new usernames as they come, or something like that. If you want to limit number of players (let's say to to three players), after each save you do the check. If you don't have three usernames yet, you clear the text input, if you do, than go to another activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks mate! Feeling so silly not thinking about that! That is for sure going to work I will implement that. And checking I actually got the amount of names desired is something I for sure should do to avoid unwanted behavior